# spring boot management end points basic security

Tags: spring-boot

How do I use basic security for management end points such as `/env, /health, /metrics`?
I want to use different user credentials for the above end points compared to the other application controller end points security.
In my application.properties file, I specified below for the application controller security

```
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=password
```

But I want different username/password for management end points. Could not find `management.security.user.name` property.

Answer (score 3):

To implement end points basic security you need to use below code

```
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=password
```

and in configuration file should be like below one

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

still not working then hope this will work

[Basic Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LV0mdCWq2wY)

Answer (score 2):

Spring security has a "global" `AuthenticationManager` configured in `@Bean` instances of type `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter`. This `AuthenticationManager` is the one that is configured by the `security.user.*` properties, unless you set `security.basic.enabled=false`. The global `AM` is also attached to the management endpoints by default, and it is the parent of any "Local" `AuthenticationManagers` defined in `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapters` (they are all `ProviderManagers`).

Thus, if you want different user accounts for management endpoints and application endpoints, you have (at least) two choices:

- Define a local `AM` for your application endpoints in a `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` and ensure that the management endpoints are not covered by that filter. This is easy, since it's what you get without thinking very much and just adding an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to your `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` (as long as it is ordered carefully in relation to the [filter that secures the management endpoints](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.java#L174)).
- Use the global `AM` (or indeed another local one) for application endpoints and reconfigure the security for the management endpoints (e.g. set `security.basic.enabled=false` and add your own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` covering the management endpoints). This might be more work, and duplicates some of the Boot defaults, but at least you will know what you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Dave already explained well, but here some complete example with using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and database as auth source.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Ignore any request that starts with /resources or /webjars
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**")
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        // for app access
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/configuration").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/auth_error")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").invalidateHttpSession(true);
         // for management access with basic auth
         http.httpBasic()
             .and()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/management/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

And this is my application.properties

**application.properties**

```
# MANAGEMENT HTTP SERVER (ManagementServerProperties) 
management.port=8081 
management.address=127.0.0.1 
management.context-path=/management 
management.security.enabled=true 

# MVC ONLY ENDPOINTS 
endpoints.jolokia.path=/jolokia 
endpoints.jolokia.sensitive=true 
endpoints.jolokia.enabled=true 

# JMX ENDPOINT (EndpointMBeanExportProperties) 
endpoints.jmx.enabled=true 
endpoints.jmx.domain=org.springboot 
endpoints.jmx.unique-names=false 

# ENDPOINT 
endpoints.enabled=true

endpoints.shutdown.id=shutdown 
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=true 
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true 

# HYPERMEDIA ENDPOINTS 
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true 
endpoints.actuator.path=/actuator 
endpoints.actuator.sensitive=false
```

You can check more endpoints properties from [spring application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

**Management Request Example**

There is ADMIN Role user (username: admin, password: password) already added on database.

- The example management request for shutting down

  ```
  $ curl -u admin:password -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8081/management/shutdown
  {"message":"Shutting down, bye..."}
  ```
- The example management request for checking HeapMemoryUsage and ThreadCount via jolokia

  ```
  $ curl -u admin:password http://127.0.0.1:8081/management/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage
  {"request":{"mbean":"java.lang:type=Memory","attribute":"HeapMemoryUsage","type":"read"},"value":{"init":268435456,"committed":829947904,"max":3817865216,"used":466033000},"timestamp":1444167809,"status":200}


  $ curl -u admin:password http://127.0.0.1:8081/management/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Threading/ThreadCount
  {"request":{"mbean":"java.lang:type=Threading","attribute":"ThreadCount","type":"read"},"value":47,"timestamp":1444174639,"status":200}
  ```
- The example management request for checking health

  ```
  $ curl -u admin:password http://127.0.0.1:8081/management/health
  {"status":"UP","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","free":163634987008,"threshold":10485760},"db":{"status":"UP","database":"H2","hello":1}}
  ```